# Problems with images in lyx

Tags: graphics, errors, lyx

I have been writing a chapter of my thesis using Lyx. Everything was normal until I put the last image in the project. When I am trying to generate the DVI file I got this error message:

```
LaTeX Error: 'File 8D_***path to my image***'.

LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in 8D_***"location of the image inside the .lyx file"***.
```

I don't understand why this happening because this image has the same extension of the other (`.png`), besides is not bigger than some of those. I tried to put the image in the same folder but this did not work, I also changed the extension to `.bmp` but it was worse.

What could happen?

Comment: A few questions: 1) What exactly is the name of the file you are using, and the path? In particular, are there any spaces or special characters. 2) Are you sure you have other `.png` files included using a DVI-based route? Normally one would expect you to have `.eps` files for these. The `.log` file will tell you. 3) Can you cut down your input to just the problematic file and minimal additions so you can post the `.lyx` file as an edit?

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks a lot for you replay. So this is the thing: the file is called "thesis.lyx", the path is "D:\Thesis\documentos". The paths of the images are: "D:\Thesis\docs\First chapter\images" and "D:\Thesis\docs\second chapter\images". As I said before, for the first chapter there is not problem, but with the second when I put the images I got that error message. All the images are .png, so for me there is not any difference between this 2 folder, the length of both paths are pretty much similar and the image in folder 2 is smaller than others in the first one.

Comment: What if you try to remove all spaces from file and folder names? What if you try to create a PDF directly?

Comment: It worked by removing the spaces from the file. Thanks a lot